# RelativeLayout layout issue in Item Layout of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am working with a ListView item layout, but I can't arrange the child positions in a Relativelayout.

Here is my Item Layout frame:

[image: http://img1.ph.126.net/-8STCR3xg1fcGkSNFcgLXw==/6630338789490053350.png]

**I want The First ImageView on the top, one TextView in center, and the second ImageView on the bottom.**

Here is my layout code(The Green RelativeLayout)

```
<RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/bub_right"
              android:layout_width="30dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignTop="@id/bub_left"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bub_left"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:background="#666666"
              android:gravity="right">
              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="30dip"
                  android:layout_height="20dip"
                  android:id="@+id/bub_up"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:src="@drawable/up"/>
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="30dip"
                  android:layout_height="20dip"
                  android:text="123"
                  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                  android:id="@+id/bub_score"
                  android:textSize="15dp"/>
              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/bub_down"
                  android:layout_width="30dip"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_height="20dip"
                  android:src="@drawable/down"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I set these two lines to make sure The Green Relativelayout has the same height as the Red one.

```
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/bub_left"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bub_left"
```

And the result is like this:

[image: http://img1.ph.126.net/eBWSYfX51mO-7_2X9X55Xw==/6630524606955145426.png]

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: broken links, please fix

Comment: Your RelativeLayout is `structured as a LinearLayout` (except for the `alignParentXYZ` attributes)... Do you really need a ReltiveLayout? `I see no use of children relativity`.

Comment: can you sample draw what you actually expecting ?

Comment: @DerGolem I use RelativeLayout because i want the three children be Top,Center,Bottom

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain OK ,wait a minute

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain i want it like this.http://img1.ph.126.net/Nau8D4xqkcTzfb00Q3S2Sg==/6630167265676117774.png

Comment: @DerGolem I set Parent to LinearLayout and add<android:orientation="vertical">Then i use android:layout_gravity:top/center/bottom for child.It's not working right.

Comment: @DerGolem  http://img2.ph.126.net/qjVGo34vZ_I5aYf72us88g==/6630511412815614086.png

Comment: @DerGolem Yes ,you are right,but i want three children to be top,center,bottom,how can i achieve that with LinearLayout.Besides, in the LinearLayout i set android:layout_alignTop,and android:layout_alignBottom to make sure height is same as The Red RelativeLayout,this is gap in between.See this,I mark the LinearLayout background with color,http://img0.ph.126.net/0zRa6mraj1z2BJ_eIl5zUQ==/6630678538583300895.png

Comment: @DerGolem if i understand your words right. I think it's not a proper way,Because the ItemLayout would stretch if the content get more,and the height of LinearLayout is also get bigger,in that situation,your method cannot always keep the first view on TOP,and last view on Bottom,if i set margin for them.

Comment: @DerGolem that's a draw flaw.What i want is Set Bold.The First ImageView on the top, one TextView in center, and the second ImageView on the bottom.This is the key demand.

Comment: @DerGolem sorry maybe i didn't catch you.In the code i posted,i didn't add any margin to any view.

Comment: You have to set the parent View's height as `match_parent`, not as `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your activity with this code. And check the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bub_right"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Side layout" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bub_up"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bub_score"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bub_down"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes exact this code. After that you can use you icons from drawable. First Check it

Comment: I put the result image over there. you want like this?

Comment: I want like this http://img1.ph.126.net/Nau8D4xqkcTzfb00Q3S2Sg==/6630167265676117774.png  i added these lines to your LinearLayout.<                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"> and the result is this.http://img2.ph.126.net/Zxw2BpvXENkY9PsHBGFo9w==/6630821475094919432.png

Comment: Your code did arrange the children view right.But Within my code ,I need this LinearLayout to be right of the main content layout.See it here http://img1.ph.126.net/-8STCR3xg1fcGkSNFcgLXw==/6630338789490053350.png

Comment: Check my code now. And replace your xml with this code. i arranged according to your requirements

Comment: Thanks for your code,it should work,i noticed that you split the left part and right part with 4:1,but i want the right side width to be constant,and the left fill the rest.How can i achieve that with your code?

Comment: Check now. I given fixed size to right side layout which is 40dp. put that size according to your requirements

Comment: It worked! You are the man!The result is like this.http://img2.ph.126.net/7UORJHWOP948rxmP3Rfbzw==/6630612567885644120.png  The only problem is the textview with android:drawableTop make my arrow up and arrow down icon looks weird,  it should be looks like this,http://img1.ph.126.net/Nau8D4xqkcTzfb00Q3S2Sg==/6630167265676117774.png.Can i change them to ImageView?How

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="hii" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="hii" />
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="hii" />
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="hii" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code ,and the result is like this.In listview.http://img0.ph.126.net/7srF3Q0GQD14gKxyAOzjMg==/6630386068490048508.png

Comment: this is one row of ur listview?

Comment: Well, i have posted this code after checking how it looks seperately as a layout. May be you have already set any attribute in your listview, so it will be conflicting with Relative Layout properties.